# BigCommerce - Find Customers by Tax Code?

Tags: bigcommerce, tax

Is there a way to find customers with a non-blank tax_exempt_category?  I can see that it's a returned value, but I can't see a way to query or filter by it and I don't want to have to process all customers.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, do you intend to use a specific language?

Comment: I don't mean to be a nuisance, but while I am, I imagine this is an excellent question for the Reddit community, whereas StackOverFlow requires more information like: example codes, expected output, and error. However, as I like to help the community, I would like to share with you a solution that can be quite simple: using PySpark in your Python code. PySpark is a framework for BigData and allows you to perform quick queries in multiple threads. Search further in the [official](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/) documentation

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a straight command I can run through curl.  I just don't know if there's a parameter for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a CURL request to get all customers with TAX exempt code "EXeMPT" -
`curl --location --request GET 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/[STORE_HASH]/v2/customers?tax_exempt_category=EXeMPT' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'Accept: application/json' \ --header 'X-Auth-Token: [YOUR_TOKEN]' \ --header 'Authorization: Basic [YOUR_CREDS]'`